# TypeError: 'Key' object not callable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to call up a specific model of an entity in the google app store with this code in python:

```
class Profile(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            user = users.get_current_user()
            user_db_qry = User.query(User.theid == user.federated_identity())
            #theid is how I have saved each user's federated id in the User entity in the datastore
            user_db_list = user_db_qry.fetch(1)
            profile_user = user_db_list[0]
            profile_id = profile_user.key().id_or_name()
            #I am trying to get the datastore created ID/Name here and this is the line that gives me the error

            self.redirect('/profile/%s' % str(profile_id))
        else:
            self.redirect("/about")
```

So I am not quite sure what is going wrong.  Is my query incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*To preface, I don't have any experience with GAE. This answer is based purely on the API docs*

The docs claim that only model instances have a `key()` method which returns a [`Key` class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_id_or_name). Though, the [`User` class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass#User_nickname) seems to be its own kind of entity.

Instead of trying to access a key instance, you may just be able to use the direct methods:

```
profile_id = profile_user.user_id()
profile_nick = profile_user.nickname()
```

If you want to investigate what the `key` member of the user contains, you could debug by checking it out:

```
print type(profile_user.key)
print dir(profile_user.key)
```

**Update**

In your comments you clarified that you are using the [`NDB` variants](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) which explains the issue. The [NDB Key Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass) is different from the DB [Key Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_id_or_name). It has no `id_or_name()` method. What it has is:

> **id()** Returns the string or integer id in the last (kind, id) pair, or
>   None if the key is incomplete.
>
> **string_id()** Returns the string id in the last (kind, id) pair, or None
>   if the key has an integer id or is incomplete.
>
> **integer_id()** Returns the integer id in the last (kind, id) pair, or
>   None if the key has an string id or is incomplete.

Comment: user_id() just returns either a unique address for google users and nothing for others, I am using my own User class and the datastore's ID method

Comment: @exployre: Your comment on Amber's answer just clarified it more. Updated

Comment: +1 since this goes into a lot more detail to accomplishing the end goal.

Comment: @Amber: To be perfectly honest, I think you would have ended up writing about the same thing had you seen the OP provide that crucial info before I did. Thanks!

Comment: okay thanks! but now id() is returning None which the docs say can happen when the key is incomplete.  now I haven't made the key anywhere, but do I need to do that for the default id? ( I can't quite make sense of the docs or find a good example)

Comment: @exployre: I wish I could comment on that part, but like I said I don't actually have any GAE experience so I am not sure what circumstances result in an incomplete key. This is probably a completely new issue that you might want to post as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

```
        profile_id = profile_user.key().id_or_name()
```

doesn't need the first set of parens.

```
        profile_id = profile_user.key.id_or_name()
```

Comment: then it tells me:     profile_id = profile_user.key.id_or_name()
AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'id_or_name' even though when I go to the datastore viewer I can see my User objects have an attribute ID/Name that was automatically created

Comment: could it have anything to do with the fact that I am using User(nbd.model) and not User(db.model)?

Comment: Yes it does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875903/how-do-i-get-the-key-for-the-current-record-in-gae-ndb-in-a-python-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've written other places, how have you been allocating keys for your entities?  Are you giving them names instead?

If you are using a key path ending in something like this: (note: I *don't* mean parent, just key path)

```
ndb.Key.from_path(..."User", "harold")
```

for your keys, then the keys will return None for their id but *should* (if `ndb` works similarly to `db`) have a name attribute.

The easiest way to figure this out is to run your app in the SDK and go to `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin` , open up the interactive console and try (possibly all) the properties until you get the one you want. With app engine, it often helps catch weird errors (for example, many of the API calls specifically fail if you try to use them with kewyord arguments instead of positional arguments, etc)

i'd also suggest trying to do a lookup from key you generate from `ndb.Key.from_path()` to a user instance and see if you are correctly instantiating/getting/whatever your keys.