# How do I get the key for the current record in GAE ndb in a Python for loop?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I currently have a web page that presents a list of records from a datastore with an edit link.  I want to convert this from db. to ndb.  I am a Python and GAE newbie.

The current code =

```
  <tbody>
    {% for listtype in listtypes %}
    <tr>
      <td> {{ listtype.ListTypeName }} </td>
      <td><a href ="/listtypes/edit/{{ listtype.key().id() }}">edit </a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}    
  </tbody>
```

Then on the .py side, I have:

```
def post(self, listtype_id):
    iden = int(listtype_id)
    listtypes = db.get(db.Key.from_path('ListTypes', iden))
    listtypes.ListTypeName = self.request.get('ListTypeName')
    listtypes.put()
```

I got to these by copying someone else's code bbut it works.  I need to know what the code would look like to make it work with ndb. (I am ok with the model and the include statements, I just need to know how to retrieve the key in the jinja2 template and how to use it in the post function.

Please provide what the actuall code should look to make this work with ndb.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With NDB key is an attribute not a method.  So you `listtype.key().id()` should be `listtype.key.id()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This enabes the html template to display the correct link.  However, on the 

    def get(self, lang_id):
        iden = int(lang_id)
        listtypes = ndb.get(ndb.Key.from_path('ListTypes', iden))

I get the error that get listtypes = ndb.get(ndb.Key.from_path('ListTypes', iden))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'

What does the code on the get side in the edit function need to look like?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the statement I presented on the .py is not the datastore example that is working correctly.  Thet code =

    listtypes = db.get(db.Key.from_path('ListTypes', iden))

The bottom line is that I am looking for the equivalent to this for NDB.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi its probably time to start reading the docs.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities

Comment: I have been going over this documentation repeatedly for days but an unable to interpolate what I need from the documentation.  The documentation gives an example to retrieve an entity: sandy = sandy_key.get().  They also have an example to retrieve the ID for an entity = ident = rev_key.id().  In my case I need to be able to retrieve the entity from the ident.  I do not know the key.  What is the NDB statement to retrieve an entity from an ident if you do not have the key?  Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to get an entity given the Id and kind then you can construct a key.  In your example above you are trying to use key_from_path which isn't in ndb.  Have a look at the key constructor arguments.  class Key(flat=[kind1, id1, kind2, id2, ...])
 Is pretty much exactly the same thing.  see the ndb reference. Once you have constructed the key then you can call get()

Comment: I found the following which is working.  listtype = ndb.Key('ListTypes', ident).get() Is there any reason I should not use it?  Thanks.

Comment: Yep that's just what I was telling you about,.  A path in a key is the kind,Id. A sequence of these includes the parent(s).  As I said you should have a read about keys in ndb and appengine in general.